# Cloudinit file inside terraform config file not working

Tags: linux, unix, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, cloud-init

I'm trying to run a cloudinit file by passing it in the terraform config file. The terraform apply command creates all the resources. But when i spin up the VM, none of the changes from the cloudinit are seen in the VM.

Here is the Cloudinit file with .tpl extension:

```
users:
- name: ansible
  gecos: Ansible
  sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
  groups: [users, admin]
  shell: /bin/bash
  ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1.......
```

And here is the main.tf file:

```
data "template_file" "users_data" {
  template = file("./sshPass.tpl")
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  part {
  content_type = "text/cloud-config"
  content      = data.template_file.users_data.rendered
}

  resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "poc-vm" {


    name                  = var.vm_name
    resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.poc_rg.name
    location              = azurerm_resource_group.poc_rg.location
    size                  = var.virtual_machine_size
    admin_username        = var.vm_username
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.poc_nic_1.id]

    admin_ssh_key {
      username   = var.vm_username
      public_key = tls_private_key.poc_key.public_key_openssh
    }

    os_disk {
      caching              = var.disk_caching
      storage_account_type = var.storage_type
    }

    source_image_reference {
     publisher = var.image_publisher
     offer     = var.image_offer
     sku       = var.image_sku
     version   = var.image_version
    }

    user_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the errors. Changed the extension to '.cfg.'. Added 'custom_data' instead of user_data.
Added '#cloud-config' to the 1st line of the file.
Made sure I removed any spaces at end of my ssh key.
And also felt like I was using the wrong ssh key to login the whole time.
But anyways those things helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  part {
  content_type = "text/cloud-config"
  content      = "${data.template_file.users_data.rendered}"
}
```

In this example I change this line `content = data.template_file.users_data.rendered` for this one `content = "${data.template_file.users_data.rendered}"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does not work. Still cannot see any changes

Comment: In the block of your VM instead of `user_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered` use `custom_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered`

Comment: Yeah I did that along with adding #cloud-config to the 1st line of the file. It worked !

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with an `aws_instance` in terraform. Adding `user_data_replace_on_change = true` fixed the issue for me, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_instance" "reverse_proxy" {
  ami                         = "ami-0ea18256de20ecdfc" # UBUNTU
  instance_type               = "t2.nano"
  user_data_base64            = data.cloudinit_config.config.rendered
  user_data_replace_on_change = true # TOGGLE THIS HERE
  subnet_id                   = var.reverse_proxy_subnet_id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name                    = var.key_name

  vpc_security_group_ids = var.reverse_proxy_security_group_ids

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.app_name}-load-balancer"
  }

}
```